# Windows Application .. Not working

Tags: c#

after I did this application using visual C# ... Simply nothing on the form is working its like disconnected any ideas why ?

Comment: From your question, your issue can't be resolved. So better post some code.

Comment: Using my psychic debugging skills, I sense that your problems lies on line ... 47, yes, that's it, line 47 :-) No? Well, the I guess you'd better post some code.

Comment: @paxdiablo ...lol I was checking the line 47

Comment: Hehe. You improved you comment style - good! And (some) event handlers got better name - good!

Comment: I think you should replace the programmer.

Comment: Why do you remove the code after you get an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the event handlers for the Button.Click events are set. Visual Studio tends to drop the event handlers some times.

Open up your form in design mode and check if the click event is set for your buttons by inspecting them in the property grid. If they aren't then you can reselect the method using the drop-down menu.